# Are there spreadsheet functions to query route planner for travel time and distance?

Tags: google-docs

I would like to realise a spreadsheet where the columns are as follows.

| Place A | Place B | Distance by road between A and B | Travel time by road between A and B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I thought this might be possible using the 'Google' functions of Google Docs' spreadsheet, but I've found none that does the trick.

In the end, I could knock up an app to do this using the Google Maps API, but I would rather avoid it if I can.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*MapQuest* seems to be the best bet, as they have a URL-based API for directions, whereas *Google Maps* seems to be a *JavaScript* library.

This worked for me in a *Google Docs Spreadsheet*. This one gets the distance (miles):

```
=importXML("http://mapquestapi.com/directions/v1/route?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&outFormat=xml&from=" & A2 & "&to=" & B2,"//response/route/distance")
```

And this one gets the time (formatted in *hh:mm:ss*):

```
=importXML("http://mapquestapi.com/directions/v1/route?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&outFormat=xml&from=" & A2 & "&to=" & B2,"//response/route/formattedTime")
```

where *A2* is the origin and *B2* is the destination.

You have to get an API key from *MapQuest* and replace the value *YOUR_KEY_HERE* with it.